# post form submit values getting empty in codeigniter after editing htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I tried a form submit But I am not able to get the form values on controller.Before it worked for me.But now to remove index.php from URL I replaced htaccess file.From then it is retuning empty data.Here is htaccess file.I referred this link [not able get post form submit values in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786013/not-able-get-post-form-submit-values-in-codeigniter/30273378#30273378) and replaced htaccess file then POST is working but "index.php" in URL is not removing.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
        #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
       ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Controller Code:

```
public function checklogin() {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('session');

    $data = array(
        'email'  => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password'    => $this->input->post('password'),
    );
    print_r($data);
}
```

Form:

```
<form action="firstpage/checklogin" method="post" name="form1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 responsive-center">
            <label for="login"> Email ID</label>
            <input type="text" id="login" value="" name="email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 responsive-center">
            <label for="login" style="color:#666666;float: left;">Password </label>
            <input type="password" id="password" value="" name="password"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 responsive-center">
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" id="submit" name="submita"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Post your controller and Form Where Been Sumitted

Comment: You have no codeigniter form validation set up on controller function need that to submit data and your action has no base url http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: action="<?php echo base_url('firstpage/checklogin');?>"  because you have removed index.php you may need to set up routes also.

Comment: Tried even though getting empty array

Comment: If you need to try different htaccess you can download them here suitable for codeigniter https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: Have you set up form_validation->run etc on controller I can not see it set rules and stuff http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: Yes I tried above access files but I am getting page not found error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786013/not-able-get-post-form-submit-values-in-codeigniter/30273378#30273378 In this post they edited the htaccess file they solved the Issue for me it is not working