# Codeigniter - HTML <select> returns no value on controller post

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="gender" id="gender" required >
      <option value="">- select -</option>
      <option>Male</option>
      <option>Female</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

And on my controller I try to retrieve the value:

```
echo $this->input->post('gender'); // but returns no value
echo $_POST['gender']; // same here, no value
```

But when I try to use this:

```
<input type='text' value='Male' name='gender' id='gender'>
```

It returns the value

```
echo $this->input->post('gender'); // returns Male
echo $_POST['gender']; // returns Male
```

I also tried to edit the options to:

```
<select class="form-control" name="gender" id="gender" required >
  <option value="">- select -</option>
  <option value="Male">Male</option>
  <option value="Female">Female</option>
</select>
```

Still no luck.

Why? 
I looked up for some related questions but most of them are database-driven options. I am only using hard coded options so most of the answers I found around doesn't help.
Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Please Try $all_posted_data = $this->input->post();  this code get all the posted data so you don't need to get separate post data for all field. Try this and get back the result. Using this you can get a array of all posted data.

Comment: is this the single input or you have more input to post? @Jorz

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786013/not-able-get-post-form-submit-values-in-codeigniter

Comment: @ankitsuthar aside from gender selects, I also have a select for job positions, which also returns no value. I can only retrieve values from textboxes

Comment: I will try to check the link @Naga. Thanks.

Comment: could you please post your whole form?

Comment: Your select tag is looking correct.  Have you tried to get all the post data by input->post() ? is this gender field shows the empty value ?

Comment: @ankitsuthar i used print_r($this->input->post()) on controller and I got this: Array ( [id] => 10069 )  I only got the ID. Gender is not included in the array.

Comment: Ok then maybe the problem is something else,  because if your select send empty value then this array show the gender field with blank value & here your form did not post the gender input to the controller. Recheck your controller or form action or if possible show the complete controller and view code here in the question.

Comment: @Jorz can you please share the form submit action. How are you sending the data to controller.

Comment: Hi guys. I found another way around. I used javascript onchange() to pass the selected value into textboxes. Then I'll get their names on the controller.  Everything runs smoothly now. Btw thank you guys for all your responses. :)

Comment: Are you using some kind of middleware to validate post data? Perhaps you haven't set the correct form validation / middleware and therefor it will empty the post data.